# FFmpeg - EXRs to MOV, repeating first 24 frames

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, openexr

I'm trying to convert EXRs to h264:MOV, in their native resolution. It will create the QT, but when I play back it back, it is looping the first 24 frames, over and over for what seems to be the duration of the frame sequence.

Below is the command I'm running, Along with Output:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg_build2/ffmpeg -start_number 001001 -r 24 -i /Volumes/storage/ff/plates/BC/BC0535/BC0535_ref2_20150408/2880x2160/EXR/BC0535_ref2.%06d.exr -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24 /Volumes/vfx_sftp/ff/ff_prod/TO_PROD/Fan4_BC_QT_PT2_20150515/BC0535_ref2_fr_20.mov
```

Comment: How are you playing the video? And how many frames does the video has?

Comment: Correction: Every 16 frames is starts over.

Comment: Playing the video in standard quicktime player, and it has 68 frames.

Comment: full command line and console output please?

Answer (score 0):

```html
[libx264 @ 0x34e1aa0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x34e1aa0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x34e1aa0] profile High, level 5.1
[libx264 @ 0x34e1aa0] 264 - core 144 r96 40bb568 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=48 lookahead_threads=8 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to '/Volumes/vfx_sftp/ff/ff_prod/TO_PROD/Fan4_BC_QT_PT2_20150515/BC0535_ref2_fr_20.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2880x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.21.102 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (exr (native) -> h264 (libx264))
```